# Почему справа и слева отступы нулевые, а сверху и снизу ненулевые?

Tags: css

Вопрос в следующем: Почему справа и слева отступы нулевые, а сверху и снизу ненулевые? Как это можно исправить?

Код:

```
<div style="background-color: #981233; display:inline-block; color:#FFFFFF;  font-size:60pt;"><b>SMIMARKETING</b></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: есть еще такое понятие для шрифтов как межстрочное расстояние: line-height

Comment: И как его применить сюда, чтобы отступы пропали? Не могу понять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите на сайт [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru) и добавьте его в закладки, там показано много примеров использование тех или иных атрибутов css. Найдите line-height и будет Вам счастие.